# Setting up Akka with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt, akka

I am trying to get a simple Akka program building with Eclipse and Scala. I used g8 to create the sbt project with Akka(g8 typesafehub/akka-scala-sbt) and then sbteclispe to create the Eclipse project. When I import the project into Eclipse I'm given errors saying I am missing Akka. Is there any way that I can build an Akka project with Eclipse?

Comment: I have the same problem with Lift-web, but, I use Eclipse as an IDE, and then I use sbt to built and test my project.  It may be that you just need to add the Akka jars to your project directly.

Comment: When I manually add the classes to my class path I get the error. class file needed by ActorSystem is missing. reference value typesafe of package com refers to nonexisting symbol.

Comment: Does the project build and run with `sbt`?

Comment: It does run with sbt, but I would like to have an IDE to write code.

Comment: I found out this was due to a change in [Akka 2.0.3 onwards](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/akka-user/Jslm5nS5oaE). I solved the issue by using Akka 2.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest thing is to add the `sbteclipse` plugin to your Sbt build. It automatically generates project files for Eclipse, so that you can import your project with all its settings, classpath included. To do so, add the following under `project/plugins.sbt` (*not* in the root of your project, but under the `project` subdirectory):

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

then, start `sbt` and at the prompt write `eclipse`. You should see:

```
> eclipse
[info] About to create Eclipse project files for your project(s).
[info] Successfully created Eclipse project files for project(s):
[info] Test Project
```

Then go to Eclipse and Import your project.

Comment: I did do this, but when I imported it into eclipse akka was not recognized as a library.

Comment: Thanks for this! I redid it and for some reason worked this time.

Comment: If you already imported the project, you may need to do `Refresh`, for Eclipse to see changes on the file system. Or maybe the akka library was not yet downloaded (though `sbt eclipse` should normally do an `update` before)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for this, I can't believe what torture it is to get akka and scala working together on eclipse. Maven would have been nice, but it does a terrible thing with Scala. SBT looks like the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

I use this to start the 1.x microkernel from the IDE, I think it came from Henke:

> Main class : akka.kernel.Main
>
> VM args:
> -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Dakka.home=./kernel -Dlogback.configurationFile=src/main/resources/logback.xml

In kernel directory I have a symlink config -> ../src/main/resources

In the kernel directory I also have an empty deploy directory. Not used, but must be there.